# error: initializer element is not constant C

Tags: c, linux, sys

I keep geting

```
`error: initializer element is not constant
 FILE *file = fopen("/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/temp1_input", "r");

temperatura.c:19:14: error: expected ‘)’ before string constant
 fscanf(file ,"%s", &temp);`;
```

my entire code looks like:

```
#define  temp4M   1000
FILE *file = fopen("/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/temp1_input", "r");
char temp[temp4M];


fscanf(file ,"%s", &temp);

int main()
{
    printf(" CPU cores :%d\n", corCPU);
    printf("%s", modCPU);
    printf("%d",temp);

    return 0;
}
```

is the problem in my file path or am I missing something, note that I am reading numbers from temp1_input as string instead of numbers. what is wrong?

Comment: You can't call a function in global scope. C is not a scripting language. So the `fopen` and `fscanf` calls need to be inside of `main`.

Comment: you cannot put code outside a method. YO must move fopen, fscant etc insode main

Comment: One thing, `fscanf(file ,"%s", &temp);` should be `if(fscanf(file ,"%s", temp) != 1) { // error code }` notice I also removed the `&`. Please *always* check the return value from the `scanf` family. Otherwise it can be [GIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out).

Answer (score 1):

Code should go inside the `main` function:

```
int main()
{
    FILE *file = fopen("/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/temp1_input", "r");
    char temp[temp4M];

    fscanf(file ,"%s", &temp);

    ...
}
```

The compiler got confused by your code, which was outside the function, and mistook it for something. So it gave you confusing error messages, which don't help you see the actual problem.